# RubyMotion: uninitialized constant BubbleWrap::UIAlertViewStyleDefault

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

I just started out with RubyMotion. I cloned a sample tweets app from https://github.com/addamh/tweetr. But when i run it, i get the following error:

$ rake
     Build ./build/iPhoneSimulator-4.3-Development
  Simulate ./build/iPhoneSimulator-4.3-Development/tweetr.app
2013-05-25 16:09:00.945 tweetr[30589:11103] uninitialized constant BubbleWrap::UIAlertViewStyleDefault (NameError)

Does anyone know why that could be? Am running mac osx lion (10.7.5) with XCode 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Xcode from 4.1 to 4.6.2 fixed it.

Comment: You should accept your answer as well, might be useful to someone else to find it in the future.